# Adding NanoGUI to OpenGL project

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl

I am currently trying to get NanoGUI into my opengl project. I use GLFW and GLAD.

My issue is I can't find any documentation on how this works, I have cloned the NanoGUI Git repo, I have run cmake (not that I have any idea how to use cmake!) and I have a folder that contains a new VS solution. But what now? How do I get this into my project?

Here is the folder after the cmake.

[image: Cmake folder]

But now what do I do with this? Any library I have used before I just set up paths to .lib and include files and set up the linker?

Comment: CMake will create a VS project for you. Did you build the project? It should produce the artifacts (.lib ect) that you need.

Comment: @super I tried to run it without changing anything and got "unable to start a program the system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: What did you run? Do you have VS working on your system, can you open the project?

Comment: @super Yes, I ran the project in x64 Debug. This will be going into my FYP which is a project similar to the marmoset toolbag as I major in shader writing, my issue is I have never had to use cmake libraries before!

Comment: CMake simply creates a VS project. All you need to do after CMake has done it's job is to open the project and compile it.

Comment: I guess my issue must be with how I am using cmake as I get the "unable to start program" pop-up

Comment: I don't understand. Do you get that when you are trying to start CMake? I thought you already managed to run it...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes I had already run cmake, the error comes up when I try to compile the project.

Comment: "unable to start program" does not sound like a compiler error... What error are you getting from VS when you try to compile?

Comment: Sorry it just clicked, I was trying the project as an exe which is why it was failing to open after trying to build, set the configuration type to Utility and it produced a .lib file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build was set to an exe instead of a Utility library!

Properties->General->Configuration Type